# returning NSArray and release it

Tags: objective-c

I have this classA that has a method in it, that is being called from another classB to get the coordinates of a sprite.

when i call that method in the classA, it returns NSMutablearray, but then i want to release that array.
so if i release classA, is that ok? all the allocated array in it are being releaseD ? NO..
or should i release the array in the dealloc of the called classA ?

```
gameHandler.m
-(NSMutableArray*)stand2_Co
{
...
return myArray
}
```

and then call it from another class :

```
theLevel=[[gameHandler alloc] init];
..
..
int theNumber = [   [ [theLevel stand2_Co] objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];

[theLevel release];
```

if i release the gameHandler , i need to also release that array ?
if so, when should i do that ?

thanks a lot .

Comment: In `stand2_Co` you should create autoreleased `myArray` and return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You own any object you create

> You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”,
> “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or
> mutableCopy).

- When you no longer need it, you must relinquish ownership of an
  object you own

> You relinquish ownership of an object by sending it a release message
> or an autorelease message. In Cocoa terminology, relinquishing
> ownership of an object is therefore typically referred to as
> “releasing” an object.

- You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own

> This is just corollary of the previous policy rules, stated
> explicitly.

[Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you run the Analyzer tool and the memory leak tester to verify that nothing is being leaked.  I would suggest that you release the thEdit array specifically in your ClassA.  Anything alloc-ated should also be released either by caller or alloc-ator.

Answer (score 1):

You should `release` all objects of your class that were `retained` or `allocated` in it.

If you are using some objects from another class that you should `retain` them to be sure that they will be alive during your work in that class.

Comment: Thnaks. my problem is that when i alloc the classA and call a method in it from another classB, i cant release it in classA because the method in classA is quit after it returns a value,so i have no place to put the release line , if i put it after the return ,it will not be done, if i put it befor the return, it will release the array and not return it to classB ! ...

Comment: Then you should just return autoreleased object: `return [object autorelease];`